# Of what trumpery, of what dormant statute does Swift write in "An Argument Against Abolishing Christianity"?

Tags: allusions, jonathan-swift, an-argument-against-abolishing

*[An Argument Against Abolishing Christianity](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/An_Argument_Against_Abolishing_Christianity)* begins with following:

> It is further objected against the Gospel system that it obliges men to the belief of things too difficult for Freethinkers, and such who have shook off the prejudices that usually cling to a confined education. To which I answer, that men should be cautious how they raise objections which reflect upon the wisdom of the nation. Is not everybody freely allowed to believe whatever he pleases, and to publish his belief to the world whenever he thinks fit, especially if it serves to strengthen the party which is in the right? **Would any indifferent foreigner, who should read the trumpery lately written by Asgil, Tindal, Toland, Coward, and forty more, imagine the Gospel to be our rule of faith, and to be confirmed by Parliaments?** Does any man either believe, or say he believes, or desire to have it thought that he says he believes, one syllable of **the matter?** And is any man worse received upon that score, or does he find his want of nominal faith a disadvantage to him in the pursuit of any civil or military employment? **What if there be an old dormant statute or two against him, are they not now obsolete, to a degree, that Empson and Dudley themselves, if they were now alive, would find it impossible to put them in execution?**

Of what trumpery does Swift write? Is *the matter* to be understood as the Gospel? [Toland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Toland) is described in Wikipedia as a freethinker, are other authors also freethinkers? To what dormant statutes does the author allude?
Who were Empson and [Dudley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dudley_(surname))?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[One online version of your book](http://www.fullbooks.com/The-Prose-Works-of-Jonathan-Swift-Vol-III-1.html) offers an extensive footnote for that passage and elaborates on the four as they relate to Swift [links inserted for context]

> [John Asgill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Asgill) (1659-1738), became a member of Lincoln's Inn,
> and went over to Ireland in 1697, where he practised as a barrister,
> amassed a large fortune, and was elected to the Irish parliament. For
> writing "[An Argument, proving that Man may be translated from hence
> without passing through Death](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo2/A75693.0001.001?view=toc)," he was, in 1700, expelled from the House, and the book ordered to be burnt. On returning to England he was elected to
> parliament for Bramber, but suffered a second expulsion in 1712, also on
> account of this book. He was imprisoned for debt, and remained under the
> rules of the Fleet and King's Bench for thirty years, during which time
> he wrote and published various political tracts. His "Argument"
> attempted to "interpret the relations between God and man by the
> technical rules of English law," and [Coleridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samuel_Taylor_Coleridge) thought no little of its
> power and style.
>
> [Matthew Tindal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matthew_Tindal) (1657-1733) was born at Beer Ferrers, in Devonshire. He
> studied at Oxford, and obtained a fellowship in All Souls. He was made
> LL.D. in 1685, and, although he professed himself a Roman Catholic in
> James II.'s reign, he managed to keep his fellowship after that
> monarch's flight by becoming Protestant again. His most important work
> was "The Rights of the Christian Church Asserted," which the House of
> Commons in 1710 adjudged fit for burning by the hangman. In 1730 he
> published anonymously, the first part of "[Christianity as Old as
> Creation](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Christianity_as_Old_as_the_Creation)," a work which attacked strongly the authority of the
> Scriptures; a second volume was never published.
>
> [John Toland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Toland) (1669-1722), born near Londonderry, and educated in a
> Catholic school. He professed himself a Protestant, and was sent to
> Glasgow and Edinburgh. In the latter university he graduated in his
> master's degree. While studying at Leyden he became a sceptic, and in
> 1695 published his "[Christianity not Mysterious](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christianity_Not_Mysterious)," a work which aroused a
> wide controversy. In his "Life of Milton" (1698) he denied that King
> Charles was the author of "Eikon Basilikae," and also attacked the
> Gospels. This also brought upon him rejoinders from Dr. Blackall and Dr.
> Samuel Clarke. He died at Putney, in easy circumstances, due to the
> presents made him while visiting German courts. He wrote other works,
> chief among which may be mentioned, "Socinianism truly Stated" (1705),
> "Nazarenas" (1718), and "Tetradymus." His "Posthumous Works" were issued
> in two volumes in 1726, with a life by Des Maizeaux. Craik calls him "a
> man of utterly worthless character," and refers to his being "mixed up
> in some discreditable episodes as a political spy."
>
> [William Coward](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Coward) (1656?--1724?) was born at Winchester. He studied
> medicine and became a fellow of Wadham College, Oxford. His "Second
> Thoughts concerning Human Souls," published in 1702, occasioned fierce
> disputes, on account of its materialism. The House of Commons ordered
> the work to be burnt by the hangman.
>
> Asgill, Toland, Tindal, Collins, and Coward are classed as the Deistical
> writers of the eighteenth century. In his "History of English Thought in
> the Eighteenth Century" Mr. Leslie Stephen gives an admirable exposition
> of their views, and their special interpretation of Locke's theories.

So the trumpery to which Swift is referring are the various works by those four scholars.

Quite happily, the same book has a footnote for [Empson and Dudley](https://thehistoryofengland.co.uk/resource/henry-viis-hatchet-men-empson-and-dudley/):

> Of Henry VII. notoriety, who aided the king, by illegal
> exactions, to amass his large fortune. They were executed by Henry VIII.